# is it reasonable to get sessionid from url other than cookie? something about express-session

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

I have some domain( maybe change very frequently), and two stable domain(e.g. auth.aaa.com, api.aaa.com).

Since express-session(https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) default get sessionid from cookie, but when crossing domain,ajax won't send cookie( I don't want to use something like Access-Control-Allow-Credentials ).
I want to add the sessionid to the querystring, and forge a cookie before express-session middleware.

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    var ss = req.query.ss;
    if(ss){
        var signature = require('cookie-signature');
        var cookie = require('cookie');
        var signed = 's:' + signature.sign(ss, "secret");
        var data = cookie.serialize('jsessionids', signed);
        req.headers.cookie = data;
    }
    next();
})
app.use(session({
    name:'jsessionids',
    store: new redisStore({
        host:config.redis.host,
        port:config.redis.port,
        pass : config.redis.password,
        db: config.redis.database
    }),
    resave: false, // don't save session if unmodified
    saveUninitialized: false, // don't create session until something stored
    secret: 'secret'
}));
```

is it reasonable? or any suggestion else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *generally* not advisable to add the session as a query parameter, you have to jump through lots of hoops to get them to near the same level of security as cookies.

The main problem is that it is much more vulnerable to ***[session fixation](http://shiflett.org/articles/session-fixation)*** or ***session hijacking***, which is where an attacker can steal and use another user's session.

**Some key points to take into consideration**

- Query parameters are stored in browser history, bookmarks and referrer headers (just to name a few)  which
  could allow an attacker to use another users session on a shared
  environment. Query string based sessions are much easier to leak outside their intended scope.
- Cookies have better security mechanisms built in such as the
  `httpOnly` flag which makes the cookies in-accessible to JavaScript
  (whereas query strings are always accessible). The `secure` flag makes
  sure that cookies are only sent over a secure connection (You could
  perhaps use [HSTS](https://blog.cloudflare.com/enforce-web-policy-with-hypertext-strict-transport-security-hsts/) to help guard against MITM attacks for query string).
- A user who share a link with their sessionID in the query string
  which would allow any other user to assume their identity.

If you do decide to use the sessionID in the query string make sure you set an expiration time for the session and always to use TLS to securely transmit the session (same applies to any authentiction method).

Saying that, If you can avoid using query string based sessions, I would advise you do.